# Morlet wavelet function in the frequency domain

Tags: matlab, fft, wavelet

I've studied about Wavelet transformation but I got stuck in this case!
I have to produce this figure in Matlab:

[image]

how can I plot Morlet wavelet at different scales in frequency domain? fs=1000Hz; fft=1024 point

Comment: Which part you are having difficulties? Calculating Morlet wavelet function? Stacking plots?

Comment: My main problem is Calculating Morlet wavelet function in frequency domain, not stacking plots...  I've seen a formula for it but I can't understand probably... Just show me how can I calculate wavelet function at scale xx in frequency domain...

Comment: If you don't need to implement the Morlet wavelet (reinvent a wheel), use http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.morlet.html.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this can be useful for you:

```
n = length(xsignal);
dt = 1/fs;
xi = [(0 : (n-1)) ]* ((2 * pi)/(n*dt));
f0 = 1; omega0 = 2*pi*f0;   

Ffactor = 4*pi/(omega0 + sqrt(2+omega0^2));    
Freq = (xi*Ffactor)./(2*pi);
```